# 301 rdirect for custom URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a custom made image gallery site that I converted to WordPress, this site have few thousands link like this

```
http://www.example.net/Gallery?cmd=viewCarGallery&carID=13&pgID=1
http://www.example.net/Gallery?cmd=viewCarGallery&carID=9&pgID=1
```

All link is now converted to wordpress and now I am facing problem redirect them, I tried to using like this

```
Redirect 301 /Gallery?cmd=viewCarGallery&carID=9&pgID=1 http://www.example.net/gallery/gallery_ID
```

Please help me how can I redirect this kind of URL.

Comment: No, that its just an example, destination URL is normal wordpress post URL

Comment: ok then can you provide some real examples of before and after redirect URLs?

Answer (score 1):

A permanent 301 redirect in your .htaccess file lets search engines and others know that an old link has been replaced by a new one. It's the recommended method for directing traffic from an existing page.I added below codes in my .htaccess file.

Redirect 301 /oldfile.htm /newfile.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is mod rewrite. Take a look here http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html

It looks like a similar question https://superuser.com/questions/155139/htaccess-301-redirect-with-regular-expressions